# How do I write a regex that fit a desirable pattern and not fit another pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a simplified Java compiler. I wrote a regex for variable name:
 "(_?[a-zA-Z]+[\w]*)"

and I want to add that the name can not be certain words, like int, double, true, false...

I tryed using ^ , but it is not working.

Comment: In what language are you trying to write a Java compiler? If that's also Java, why not just using Java's own compiler?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this should do that via regular expressions but rather can be better done using a `HashSet<String>` and exclude identifier names that are contained in the set.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a RE, but it's not easy for a human to write it. Treat keywords as identifiers in the scanner and distinguish the identifiers vs keywords in the tokenizer afterwards. That should be substantially easier.

Answer (score 1):

^ is used for something else :

> ^ may appear at the beginning of a pattern to require the match to
>   occur at the very beginning of a line. For example, ^abc matches
>   abc123 but not 123abc.

consider using "(?!...)" :

> (?!...) is a negative look-ahead because it requires that the
>   specified pattern not exist.

i suggest that if it's impossible or too hard , go to real coding instead . sometimes , regular expressions can be much slower than real , optimized code , and they can be very confusing and you might have problems finding what's wrong with what you've written.

for trying out your regular expressions , check this one:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

for quick referencing , check this one:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm

Comment: I guess OP meant set negation `[^...]` instead of a BOL assertion. And as a side note, really _regular_, properly implemented REs are not to be expected to perform slower than "optimized" code. Actually, a minimal DFA generated from a RE is the most "optimized" code that can be hoped for, see also e.g.: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html (and part II and III of the same)

Comment: sure , it all depends on the case .  do note that real code has more "power" of matching rules over regular expressions , and that just like real code , bad regular expressions can make the checks very slow. example : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wbp-3BJWsU8#t=1079s

Comment: Regular expressions are not to blame for this. Instead, it looks like the java's implementation is seriously broken. This code takes 22 ms to execute at my machine: http://play.golang.org/p/0sVG_9GA1V